# Anime/cartoon about various gems giving powers to their holder

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I don't really remember if it was cartoon or anime but in this were few gems and each gem gives power to its holder.

I only remember three characters from this show:

- there was this guy, I think he was the main guy and he got this red armour suit.
- In the beginning he fought a guy who has another gem and he got like samurai armour.
- Another character I remember but not very well was this girl, and she has fire powers or something.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steven_Universe ?

Comment: Have a look at [Lensman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lensman_(1984_film)) and [Galactic Patrol Lensman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_Patrol_Lensman), which are Japanese adaptations of E. E. "Doc" Smith's [Lensman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lensman_series) series.  Power gems, yes; I don't know about the rest.

Comment: An estimate on the time period you watched it might help, general idea reminds me of Power Rangers but the cartoon versions may or may not fit into the timeline

Comment: Sounds like a lot of anime.

Answer (score 9):

I think you are looking for [*Power Stone*](https://powerstone.fandom.com/wiki/Power_Stone_(anime)). You can see the intro below:

The guy with red armor is [Falcon](https://powerstone.fandom.com/wiki/Edward_Falcon)

> [image: Falcon's Power Change]
> Falcon's Power Change is a red android-like form able to launch many missiles. He is also able to fly with the rocket on his back, but in the games, he only does so when using Power Rocket. In the anime finale, Falcon's second Power Change form, using the Light Stone, is a white jet-like android with black and yellow eyes and angelic wings.

The guy in samurai armor would be [Ryoma](https://powerstone.fandom.com/wiki/Ryoma).

> [image: Ryoma's Power Change]
> Ryoma's Power Change is a beetle-like silver samurai with electric powers.

The girl with fire powers is [Rouge](https://powerstone.fandom.com/wiki/Rouge):

> [image: Rouge's Power Change]
> Though her normal attack and defense abilities are relatively low, Rouge can wield her fire attacks from a long distance and inflict severe damage. Her running and jumping speeds are also higher than the other fighters.
>
> During Power Change, she has a genie-like appearance with fiery hair. A fireball with an eye follows her. In the anime, she can summon a magic carpet that can fly after she rescues an injured Ryoma from a burning palace, absorbing the flames in the burning shipwreck and can melt the ice when she was in her flaming appearance.

Comment: Adding character citations for those remembered.

Answer (score 3):

What you are thinking about is a show called *[Gaist Crusher](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?ann-edition=uk&id=15541)*. These crystal formations would become giant monsters and when killed and stabilized, certain people could equip and use them as armor or use Form 2 which is a giant weapon and no armor but you could train and get Form 3 which was the original Gaist's form

Answer (score 2):

There's a remote chance you're thinking of the cartoon adaptation of [The 99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_99_(TV_series)).

To summarize, the "power" of the books of Baghdad's House of Wisdom was absorbed into 99 gems before the library was destroyed by invaders.  These stones are slowly being recovered, and imbue their owners with various super powers.

The show had a brief run in the US in 2011.

Answer (score 0):

"Voltage Fighter Gowcaizer" is the anime you're thinking of.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you please describe how this matches the details of the question?