Animated show. Three guys with armor that comes out of a gemstone. The hero has a red gem and the other two are blue and green
This animated show (possibly an anime) was about a guy with red hair. He has a device that can make him have armor and when he wants to, he can change the armor into something that looks like a gem (like a red ruby).
There were two other guys that have the same device but their device are blue and green, respectively. When they need a weapon, some of the armor disappears and becomes a weapon.
At one point they need to fight a monster. I think it was a 'gem monster'(?)

Welcome blade boy. Could you edit to correct some of the odd words. Perhaps use whole words not abbreviations, and consider adding punctuation and formal sentence structure - this would help enormously with the clarity of what you're asking.

Possibly one of these; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/178655/anime-cartoon-about-various-gems-giving-powers-to-their-holder
